# ASIHTTPRequest method Alternate for AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

i was doing this in ASIHTTPRequest:

```
[request addFile:@"/Users/Salman/Downloads/asd1.jpg" forKey:@"user_image"];
```

what is its alternate in AFNetworking:

iam doing this but it is not working.

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData1 name:@"user_image" fileName:@"image3.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
```

what should do to solve this? please help.

Comment: Could you try changing mimeType from @"image/jpeg" to @"image/png" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change mimeType from @"image/jpeg" to @"image/png" and it works. thanks @Zhang